# A counterexample to the Sura-Bura Theorem for non separated compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Is there a $T_1$ compact space such that the class of quasi-components differs from the class of connected components?  By the Sura-Bura theorem, this is not possible for $T_2$ compact spaces.

Comment: For relatively recent Questions such as this, it would help Math.SE's mission to collect excellent content to add more context.  E.g., as you approached the problem, is there one direction of comparing quasi-components and connected components that is easier than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take a convergent sequence with two limits, let's say $\{0, 0'\} ∪ \{1/n: n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$. All the points $1/n$ are isolated. The neighborhood base at $0$ is $\{0\} ∪ \{1/n: n > N\}$, $N ∈ \mathbb{N}$, and similarly at $0'$: $\{0'\} ∪ \{1/n: n > N\}$, $N ∈ \mathbb{N}$.

All the singletons $\{1/n\}$ are clopen, and the two zeros can't be separated by disjoint neighborhoods, so the quasi-components are $\{0, 0'\}$, $\{1/n\}$, $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$. At the same time the space $\{0, 0'\}$ is discrete, so it is not a connected component of our space.

Note that you may obtain this space as a quotient of the sum of two convergent sequences, and also as a quotient of a Hausdorff but not compact counterexample to the Sura-Bura theorem – of the space where the points $1/n$ are replaced by vertical segments of length $1$ at $1/n$.